# Carousel in html is showing stacked picture. Not scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

i have sat and looked at this code for hours wondering why it just shows stacked pictures rather than a working carousel. maybe i missed something. please help. my code is below

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

     <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to ="0" class="acive"></li>
        <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to ="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to ="2"></li>
      </ol>

    <div class="carousel-innner">
      <div class= "item active">
        <img src="power_ranger.jpg" alt="yeah" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      <div class= "item">
        <img src="jet.jpg" alt="yeah1" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      <div class= "item">
        <img src="jl.png" alt="yeah1" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

tried using carousel-item and item and they both failed.
where might the issue be?

Comment: What are you using for carousel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes in your code.

First, a minor mistake is that your `<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">` element never closes.

But this is not why the carousel is not working...

So the second mistake that I found very funny is that the class of `<div class="carousel-innner">` is wrong. It has 3×`n` on `innner`. The correct is `<div class="carousel-inner">`.